# SQL Server Backup Size varies day to day

Tags: sql-server

I am using SIMPLE recovery mode, and I need a backup around midnight each day.  The size of the backup file changes day to day and I can't figure out why.  Example, 2 days ago size is 9.6GB, 1 day ago size is 17.7GB, today size is 2.7GB.  I am saving these backups on a 32gb thumb drive, but it keeps filling up sooner than expected due to the large files I sometimes get.  No data is being deleted between these days, some data is being added, but we are talking 100's of records, not 1000's.  Transaction log is limited to 64MB (currently at 8MB).  Running Disk Usage report shows 136MB for data file (total 144MB with transaction log).  I am okay with the 2.7GB backup, but the 5+GB backups seem excessive.  Is there a command I can run before running the backup that will help me get the smallest backup file possible?  I am currently just running `BACKUP DATABASE [DB_Name] TO DISK`.

Comment: That behavior seems odd. You're not running a differential backup, are you? I'd expect those to get bigger the further away from the last full backup you are but then come back down in size once a full backup is taken.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you running? (Enterprise, Standard, Express, ...) And specifically which version of SQL Server? (2016, 2017, 2019) Is the backup job running at the same time as other tasks? (Index Reorg / Rebuild; Statistics Update, ...).